# Would a parent's citizenship affect a UK visa application for their children?

Tags: visas, uk, uk-citizens, iraqi-citizens

My sister will travel to the UK using her British passport; she is visiting our mother for two weeks. She would like to travel to the UK with her two children, 3 and 9 years old; both are Iraqi citizens who do not have British passports and have never been to the UK. She will apply on her children's behalf; in other words, she will fill the visa application for them.

Does her nationality have any positive or negative impact on the application?

Note that my sister was born outside the UK and never lived in the UK for 3 consecutive years before the oldest child was born.

Comment: Are the children British citizens too? It's somewhat difficult to imagine circumstances as in your question where they wouldn't have inherited citizenship from their mother.

Comment: @Ulkoma: Possibly -- but that doesn't sound likely since apparently the mother's mother lives in the UK. So far my bet is on the mother thinking that _not having a passport issued yet_ somehow makes them non-citizens.

Comment: I've check and they are not, I've used [this page](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen/y/on-or-after-1-january-1983/no/no)

Comment: @user64870: That assumes that the _mother_ was born outside the UK and never lived in the UK for 3 consecutive years before the oldest child was born. Is that really the case?

Comment: I'm getting confused because there are two mothers in this question. Let's give the people letters: A lives in the UK, and is presumably a UK citizen. B is her daughter, also a UK citizen, C and D are B's children, but Iraq citizens. I think @HenningMakholm's question can be rephrased as whether B was born outside the UK and never lived in the UK for 3 consecutive years before the older of C and D was born.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Yes, that is what I was asking.

Comment: @HenningMakholm that's exactly the case.

Comment: @user64870 Can you edit the extra info into the question please.